# How To Deserialize Generic Types with Moshi?

Tags: moshi

Suppose we have this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "__typename": "Car",
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Toyota Prius",
    "numDoors": 4
  },
  {
    "__typename": "Boat",
    "id": "4567",
    "name": "U.S.S. Constitution",
    "propulsion": "SAIL"
  }
]
```

(there could be many more elements to the list; this just shows two)

I have `Car` and `Boat` POJOs that use a `Vehicle` base class for the common fields:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
  public final String id;
  public final String name;
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
  public final Integer numDoors;
}

public class Boat extends Vehicle {
  public final String propulsion;
}
```

The result of parsing this JSON should be a `List<Vehicle>`. The problem is that no JSON parser is going to know, out of the box, that `__typename` is how to distinguish a `Boat` from a `Car`.

With Gson, I can create a `JsonDeserializer<Vehicle>` that can examine the `__typename` field, identify whether this is a `Car` or `Boat`, then use `deserialize()` on the supplied `JsonDeserializationContext` to parse the particular JSON object into the appropriate type. This works fine.

However, the particular thing that I am building ought to support pluggable JSON parsers, and I thought that I would try Moshi as an alternative parser. However, this particular problem is not covered well in the Moshi documentation at the present time, and I am having difficulty figuring out how best to address it.

The closest analogue to `JsonDeserializer<T>` [is `JsonAdapter<T>`](http://square.github.io/moshi/1.x/moshi/com/squareup/moshi/JsonAdapter.html). However, `fromJson()` gets passed a `JsonReader`, which has a destructive API. To find out what the `__typename` is, I would have to be able to parse everything by hand from the `JsonReader` events. While I could call [`adapter()` on the `Moshi` instance](http://square.github.io/moshi/1.x/moshi/com/squareup/moshi/Moshi.html#adapter-java.lang.reflect.Type-) to try to invoke existing Moshi parsing logic once I know the proper concrete type, I will have consumed data off of the `JsonReader` and broken its ability to provide the complete object description anymore.

Another analogue of `JsonDeserializer<Vehicle>` would be a [`@FromJson`-annotated method](https://github.com/square/moshi#another-example) that returns a `Vehicle`. However, I cannot identify a simple thing to pass into the method. The only thing that I can think of is to create yet another POJO representing the union of all possible fields:

```
public class SemiParsedKindOfVehicle {
  public final String id;
  public final String name;
  public final Integer numDoors;
  public final String propulsion;
  public final String __typename;
}
```

Then, in theory, if I have `@FromJson Vehicle rideLikeTheWind(SemiParsedKindOfVehicle rawVehicle)` on a class that I register as a type adapter with `Moshi`, Moshi might be able to parse my JSON objects into `SemiParsedKindOfVehicle` instances and call `rideLikeTheWind()`. In there, I would look up the `__typename`, identify the type, and completely build the `Car` or `Boat` myself, returning that object.

While doable, this is a fair bit more complex than the Gson approach, and my `Car`/`Boat` scenario is on the simple end of the possible data structures that I will need to deal with.

Is there another approach to handling this with Moshi that I am missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `moshi-adapters` add-on library contains [a `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory` class](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi-adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/adapters/PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.kt). While the JavaDocs for this library do not seem to be posted, the source does contain a detailed description of its use.

The setup for the example in my question would be:

```
  private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(
      PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(Vehicle::class.java, "__typename")
        .withSubtype(Car::class.java, "Car")
        .withSubtype(Boat::class.java, "Boat")
    )
    .build()
```

Now, our `Moshi` object knows how to convert things like `List<Vehicle>` to/from JSON, based on the `__typename` property in the JSON, comparing it to `"Car"` and `"Boat"` to create the `Car` and `Boat` classes, respectively.

Comment: [new link](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi-adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/adapters/PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.kt)

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE 2019-05-25**: The [newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309507/115145) is your best bet. I am leaving my original solution here for historical reasons.

---

One thing that I had not taken into account is that you can create a type adapter using a generic type, like `Map<String, Object>`. Given that, you can create a `VehicleAdapter` that looks up `__typename`. It will be responsible for completely populating the `Car` and `Boat` instances (or, optionally, delegate that to constructors on `Car` and `Boat` that take the `Map<String, Object>` as input). Hence, this is still not quite as convenient as Gson's approach. Plus, you have to have a do-nothing `@ToJson` method, as otherwise Moshi rejects your type adapter. But, otherwise, it works, as is demonstrated by this JUnit4 test class:

```
import com.squareup.moshi.FromJson;
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter;
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi;
import com.squareup.moshi.ToJson;
import com.squareup.moshi.Types;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class Foo {
  static abstract class Vehicle {
    public String id;
    public String name;
  }

  static class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Integer numDoors;
  }

  static class Boat extends Vehicle {
    public String propulsion;
  }

  static class VehicleAdapter {
    @FromJson
    Vehicle fromJson(Map<String, Object> raw) {
      String typename=raw.get("__typename").toString();
      Vehicle result;

      if (typename.equals("Car")) {
        Car car=new Car();

        car.numDoors=((Double)raw.get("numDoors")).intValue();
        result=car;
      }
      else if (typename.equals("Boat")) {
        Boat boat=new Boat();

        boat.propulsion=raw.get("propulsion").toString();
        result=boat;
      }
      else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not identify __typename: "+typename);
      }

      result.id=raw.get("id").toString();
      result.name=raw.get("name").toString();

      return(result);
    }

    @ToJson
    String toJson(Vehicle vehicle) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Um, why is this required?");
    }
  }

  static final String JSON="[\n"+
    "  {\n"+
    "    \"__typename\": \"Car\",\n"+
    "    \"id\": \"123\",\n"+
    "    \"name\": \"Toyota Prius\",\n"+
    "    \"numDoors\": 4\n"+
    "  },\n"+
    "  {\n"+
    "    \"__typename\": \"Boat\",\n"+
    "    \"id\": \"4567\",\n"+
    "    \"name\": \"U.S.S. Constitution\",\n"+
    "    \"propulsion\": \"SAIL\"\n"+
    "  }\n"+
    "]";

  @Test
  public void deserializeGeneric() throws IOException {
    Moshi moshi=new Moshi.Builder().add(new VehicleAdapter()).build();
    Type payloadType=Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, Vehicle.class);
    JsonAdapter<List<Vehicle>> jsonAdapter=moshi.adapter(payloadType);
    List<Vehicle> result=jsonAdapter.fromJson(JSON);

    assertEquals(2, result.size());

    assertEquals(Car.class, result.get(0).getClass());

    Car car=(Car)result.get(0);

    assertEquals("123", car.id);
    assertEquals("Toyota Prius", car.name);
    assertEquals((long)4, (long)car.numDoors);

    assertEquals(Boat.class, result.get(1).getClass());

    Boat boat=(Boat)result.get(1);

    assertEquals("4567", boat.id);
    assertEquals("U.S.S. Constitution", boat.name);
    assertEquals("SAIL", boat.propulsion);
  }
}
```

Comment: Polymorphic deserialization is now supported much better in Moshi's upcoming 1.4 release. (https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/89 for links to all the details.) Thanks for the post. I'll be following the Moshi tag on SO now, so shoot over any and all questions!

Comment: @EricCochran: Thanks for the info! But, unless I am misreading matters, that issue does not appear to pertain to polymorphic deserialization.

Comment: maybe most importantly, `JsonAdapter.fromJsonValue(Object)` (https://github.com/square/moshi/pull/234/files) helps to create these values out of Maps and such.